# If $A\subseteq B$ where $A,B$ are commutative domains, and $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module is Frac$(A)\subseteq$ Frac$(B)$ finite?

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $A\subseteq B$ where $A,B$ are commutative domains and $B$ is a finitely generated $A$ module, is $\operatorname{Frac}(A)\subseteq \operatorname{Frac}(B)$ a finite field extension?

I know this extension is algebraic and every element of Frac$(B)$ satisfies a monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$. I am not sure how to prove this extension is finite and not aware of any counterexamples.

Comment: Show that a set of generators for $B$ as an $A$-module is a set of generators for $\text{Frac}(B)$ as an extension of $\text{Frac}(A)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks, that's precisely what I was trying, but it helps to know that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Here is why.

Let $S=A\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Your finiteness hypothesis implies that also $S^{-1}B$ is finitely generated as a module over $S^{-1}A$.
 Hence $S^{-1}B$ is a field since it is a  domain of finite dimension over a field.
But then you have $S^{-1}A=Frac(A) \subset S^{-1}B\subset Frac (B)$ with $ S^{-1}B$  a field: necessarily then $ Frac ( B )= S^{-1}B$ and since we already know that $S^{-1}B$ is finite dimensional over $S^{-1}A=Frac(A)$, the same holds for $Frac(B)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is much slicker than what I was trying.

Comment: @Georges: I had a follow up question. Your argument shows that $[Frac(B):Frac(A)]\leq n$ where $n$ is the number of generators of $B$ as an $A$ module. Under what conditions does equality hold? Thanks.